# Curve fitting with rounding as a part of the function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, rounding, curve-fitting

I have a numeric dataset that is divided in two lists. It is generated by a function of the form round(mx+t). I want to find the function parameters and decided to use Scipy.

I've reduced the values of both data arrays to the following example:

```
x: [26 73 269 361 757]
y: [7 21 77 103 216]
```

This is my code without rounding the result of m*x+t. So far, everything is working.

```
x_data_num = array(x_data)
y_data_num = array(y_data)

def test_func(x, m, t):
  return m*x+t

params, params_covariance = optimize.curve_fit(test_func, 
x_data_num, y_data_num)

print(params)
```

I've first tried to implement rounding using `return round(m*x+t)`, but later found out that the parameters do not consist out of values.
(`TypeError: type numpy.ndarray doesn't define __round__ method`)

Therefore I decided to use `return np.round(m*x+t)`, but it doesn't work either, leaving me with the wrong parameters [1. 1.]

I suspect that all my efforts just round the final parameters, but I'm not exactly sure where to look to find the answer. [This](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) documentation couldn't help.

Comment: hiow did you generate y_data_num? what is the parameters for you fn?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is locally constant, hence a lot of optimization methods, which rely on small increments to m and t in order to work won't behave well.

If you know some bounds for your variables m and t you can brute-force your result, either by hand (just loop over two np.arange() for m and t, and find the minimum), or by using [scipy.optimize.brute()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html).

To give a working example, with your data:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize
x_data_num = np.array([26, 73,  269, 361, 757])   
y_data_num = np.array([7, 21, 77, 103, 216]) 

def test_func(x, m, t): 
    return np.round(m*x+t) 

def func_to_minimize(p): 
    return np.sum(np.abs(test_func(x_data_num, p[0], p[1]) - y_data_num)) 


x0 = optimize.brute(func_to_minimize, ranges=[slice(-1.,1.,0.1),slice(-1.,1.,0.1)]) 

print(x0)
```

Note that this can be very slow if your slices are large/contain a lot of points.

Comment: One simple way to determine bounds is to scatterplot the data and visually draw bounding lines around the data, then find the m and t values for those two lines.